# What is the point of reverse indexing?

Tags: database, distributed-computing

I just learned about reverse indexing. The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_index) page says that

> In database management systems, a reverse key index strategy reverses
>   the key value before entering it in the index.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_index) E.g., the value
>   24538 becomes 83542 in the index. Reversing the key value is
>   particularly useful for indexing data such as sequence numbers, where
>   each new key value is greater than the prior value, i.e., values
>   monotonically increase. Reverse key indexes have become particularly
>   important in high volume transaction processing systems because they
>   reduce contention for index blocks.

Why is reversing the key value useful for indexing sequence numbers? Also, why do reverse indexes help reduce contention for index blocks in high volume systems? In short: what is the point of reverse indexing?

Comment: "reducing the key value" is not what the article says.  What's being reduced is the amount of contention for the same spot in the index.  Reversing the digits gives a useful quasi-random-scattered-ness to what are actually monotonically-incrementing values, which is very well-suited to data going into B-trees.

Answer (score 47):

In your example it refers to sequential numbers being a good application for reverse indexing. Taking the quoted number `24538`, it will be inserted in the index at a certain point. The next number in the sequence will be `24539`, which will be inserted in the index very close to the first number since the most significant digits are identical. Extending this, many sequential numbers will all require insertion at much the same point, involving a significant overhead in extending index blocks and rebalancing the index along the way.

The least significant digit of these numbers changes more rapidly than the most significant. Thus, reversing the order of the digits gives `83542` and `93542` respectively. These two numbers will be inserted into the index much further apart, and extending this to many numbers, the index will be built in a more balanced way, reducing the overhead in index management.

The operation of reversing the digits is trivial in computing terms, while managing the index can potentially involve many disk accesses, so inserting items in an index in a way that reduces the management overhead can deliver significant performance improvements.